# Convert Omniform to PDF in bulk/commandline

Tags: windows-server-2008, pdf-conversion

We have a large number of Omniform files (around 100,000). We're updating our main server OS from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008. Omniform isn't supported in Windows Server 2008 so we need to convert these files to pdf (or another viewable format).

What I've tried so far:
Using Print or PrintTo verb from inside a program using Process.StartInfo and using a PDF Writer printer.

Using Print directly from a command line using the Print verb with the PDF Writer set as the Default Printer:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\ScanSoft\OMNIFO~1.1\OmniForm.exe /p "Test.ofm"
```

Both of these Print successfully and a PDF appears. However it prints only the Form, not the Form with the entered in Data. Namely you'll get Last Name then a blank instead of showing the entered last name.

If I print to a normal printer and not a PDF Writer I get the same behavior. Form only with no entered in data appearing.

I've tried calling Nuance Tech Support and they suggested doing them manually 1 at a time. Given this would take someone about half a year of full time work to do, that's not a viable option for us.

So what I'm looking for is a solution to the command line print above

Answer (score 0):

If an "image" of the filled-in form might work for you, Omniformat might help you out. It basically converts the file to pdf using a print-to-file method, but it might help you out, since it does batch conversion.

Comment: Omniform (ofm) isn't supported by Omniformat - http://www.omniformat.com/faq.html